# Remove timer event listener

Tags: actionscript-3

so I need to remove a timer event. But the problem is, It's in another function so I can't access it.

Here's how my code goes:

-There is a Boss

-It generates bomb

-Bomb lasts for a couple of seconds before exploding (no error)

-Bomb can be removed by clicking. (generates error)

If the bomb was removed via clicking, there will be error because the time event wasn't remove. But like I said, I can't remove it because it's in another function. Help!

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var boss:MovieClip = new darklord();
this.addChild(boss);
boss.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
boss.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;

var lives:int = 3;
var maxHP:int = 2000;
var currentHP:int = maxHP;
var percentHP:Number = currentHP / maxHP;

var bombcontainer:Array = [];
var timecontainer:Array = [];

function updateHealthBar():void
{
    percentHP = currentHP / maxHP;
    healthBar.barColor.scaleX = percentHP;
}

boss.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, TapBoss);
boss.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveBoss);

function TapBoss(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    currentHP -=  10;
    if (currentHP <= 0)
    {
        currentHP = 0;
        trace("You win!");
    }
    updateHealthBar();
}

var timerBoss:Timer = new Timer(1000,60);
timerBoss.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, bosstimerhandler);
timerBoss.start();

var secondsBoss:Number = 0;

function bosstimerhandler(event:TimerEvent)
{
//trace("Seconds elapsed: " + seconds);
//SpawnNote(null);
    if (secondsBoss%5==0)
    {
        RandomCoord(null);
        BossAttack(null);
    }
    secondsBoss++;
}

var HighH:int = stage.stageHeight;
var HighW:int = stage.stageWidth;
var LowH:int = 0;
var LowW:int = 0;

var destinationX:int;
var destinationY:int;

function RandomCoord(event:Event):void
{
    destinationX=Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+HighW-LowW))+LowW;
    destinationY=Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+HighH-LowH))+LowH;

    if (destinationX <= 50)
    {
        destinationX +=  50;
    }

    if (destinationY <= 50)
{
    destinationY +=  50;
}

if (destinationX + 50 >= stage.stageWidth)
{
    destinationX -=  50;
}

if (destinationY + 50 >= stage.stageHeight)
{
    destinationY -=  50;
}

    trace("X is: ", destinationX);
    trace("Y is: ", destinationY);
}

function MoveBoss(event:Event):void
{
    if (boss.x < destinationX)
{
    boss.x +=  1;
}
else if (boss.x > destinationX)
{
    boss.x -=  1;
}

if (boss.y < destinationY)
{
    boss.y +=  1;
}
else if (boss.y > destinationY)
{
    boss.y -=  1;
}
}

function BossAttack(event:Event):void
{
    var boom:MovieClip = new Bomb();
    this.addChild(boom);
    bombcontainer.push(boom);
    boom.x = boss.x;
    boom.y = boss.y;
    BombCoord(null);
    boom.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveBomb);
    boom.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, TapBomb(boom));
    BombTimer(boom);
}

function BombTimer(boom:MovieClip):void
{       
var time:Timer = new Timer(1000,30);    
timecontainer.push(time);
time.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, TimeHandler);
time.start();

var t:Number = 1;

function TimeHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{

    trace("Seconds elapsed: " + t);
    t++;
    if (t==12)
    {
        lives--;
        trace("You lost a life!");
        time.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, TimeHandler);
        RemoveBomb(boom, 0);
    }
    }
}

function RemoveBomb(boom:DisplayObject, bid:int):void
{
boom.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveBomb);  
//boom.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, TapBomb(boom)); 
bombcontainer.splice(bid, 1);
trace("Bomb # :" +bid+" is popped.");
this.removeChild(boom);
}

var BombX:int;
var BombY:int;

function BombCoord(event:Event):void
{
BombX=Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+HighW-LowW))+LowW;
BombY=Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+HighH-LowH))+LowH;

if (BombX <= 50)
{
    BombX +=  50;
}

if (BombY <= 50)
{
    BombY +=  50;
}

if (BombX + 50 >= stage.stageWidth)
{
    BombX -=  50;
}

if (BombY + 50 >= stage.stageHeight)
{
    BombY -=  50;
}
}

function MoveBomb(event:Event):void
{
var boom:DisplayObject = event.target as DisplayObject;

var fl_TimerInstance:Timer = new Timer(1000,6);
fl_TimerInstance.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, fl_TimerHandler);
fl_TimerInstance.start();

var fl_SecondsElapsed:Number = 1;

function fl_TimerHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
{
    //trace("Seconds elapsed: " + fl_SecondsElapsed);
    fl_SecondsElapsed++;
    if (fl_SecondsElapsed==4)
    {
        boom.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveBomb);
    }
}

if (boom.x < BombX)
{
    boom.x +=  5;
    //boom.x +=5;
}
else if (boom.x > BombX)
{
    boom.x -=  5;
}//boom.x -=5;

if (boom.y < BombY)
{
    boom.y +=  5;
    //boom.x +=5;
}
else if (boom.y > BombY)
{
    boom.y -=  5;
}

if (boom.x == BombX)
{
    if (boom.y == BombY)
    {
        boom.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveBomb);
    }
}

if (boom.y == BombY)
{
    if (boom.x == BombX)
    {
        boom.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, MoveBomb);
    }
}
}

function TapBomb(boom:MovieClip):Function
{
return function(e:MouseEvent):void {    
var BombIndex:int = bombcontainer.indexOf(boom);
trace("You clicked the bomb at index " + BombIndex);    
RemoveBomb(boom, BombIndex);    
}
}
```

Comment: This is bad coding anyway. You can't add an enterframe listener to every single object (like your bombs) this is too CPU expensive. You need one enterframe listener and update everything inside of it.

Comment: But it's the only way I know. :(

Comment: and in those enterframe created for each bomb you create a new Timer on EACH FRAME! There's no way your app can run even 5 minutes. This is insane, read a few tutorial before trying to code anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that bad having a frame event listener on each bomb, unless perhaps you have hundreds of bombs at the same time.

You can solve the issue by making the Bomb a separate class that has its own handlers and timer. Something like this (not tested):

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class Bomb extends MovieClip {

    private var myTimer:Timer;

    public function Bomb() {
        myTimer = new Timer(1000,30);
        myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, TimeHandler);
        myTimer.start();
    }

    private function TimeHandler(event:TimerEvent):void {
        // check the time
    }

    public function stopTicking():void {
        this.myTimer.stop();
    }
}
}
```

You can then create all the bombs you want and kill their timers by calling their method:

```
// create a bomb movieclip and add it to the displaylist
var myBomb = new Bomb();
bombContainer.addChild(myBomb);

// use the displaylist to keep track of nonexploded bombs
var someBomb = bombContainer.getChildAt(0);
// stop the timer on this bomb
someBomb.stopTicking();
```